# What' the difference between CCMoveTo and CCJumpTo?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I tried both the actions but I get same results.

CCMOveTo:

```
CCMoveTo *moveimage1=[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:CGPointMake(100, 100)];

CCMoveTo *moveimage2=[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:CGPointMake(WindowSize.width/2, WindowSize.height/2)];
CCSequence *sequence=[CCSequence actions:moveimage1,moveimage2,nil];

[FirstImage runAction:sequence];
```

CCJumpTo:

```
CCJumpTo *JumpImage1=[CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:CGPointMake(100, 100) height:0.0 jumps:2];

CCJumpTo *JumpImage2=[CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:CGPointMake(WindowSize.width/2, WindowSize.height/2) height:0.0 jumps:2];

CCSequence *sequence1=[CCSequence actions:JumpImage1,JumpImage2,nil];

[FirstImage runAction:sequence1];
```

Comment: i guess you want to know the difference Between CCMoveTo & CCMoveBy .. if yes then allow my edit..

Comment: hello Jok, i real want difference of CCMoveTo and CCJumpTo

Comment: Be clear on what you want to ask ...

Comment: Actually the problem is that you are giving height 0 in CCJumpTo. Thats why it is giving similar behavior. If you really want to see the difference  between CCJumpto and CCMoveTo , then As a action name suggest "CCJumpTo": you must give some hight in that.Then aslo, If you are not fining any difference then let me know. Think simple and then code. Don't code without thinking.

Comment: And as Shaqir says Be clear about what you are coding and what's your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Difference Between CCMoveTo & CCMoveBy

```
CCMoveTo :
```

it will take your image to particular location.
Example :

```
CCMoveTo *moveimage1=[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0 position:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

This will take you to (100,100) position on screen , Irrespective to your image position ,means it does not matter what is  your image's current location is.In this case current position of sprite doesn't matter.....

While ,

```
CCMoveBy :
```

it will take your image to particular location.
Example :

```
CCMoveBy *moveimage1=[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2.0 position:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

This will move your position with (100,100) on x & y position , means if Your image  at (50,50) position then you will be moved by (100,100) to (150,150) position . so in this case(CCMoveBy) your image's current position matters.

Comment: I say CCJumpTo And CCMoveTo Got same result,Why?